# How to find the height of the triangular prism?

Tags: geometry

So I already know how to calculate base area given all 3 edges. I need to use Herom Formula. Now I'm left with finding the height of the prism. What formula should I apply here to find the height of the prism given that I already have surface area of 1620cm (Sqr) and base area of 360cm(sqr) ? Pic of the prism:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express the surface area by the height of the prism to have an equation. Note, for example, that the quadrilateral $A_1B_1BA$ is a rectangle (which I assume from the image).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how can I express the surface area by the height of the prism when I don't know what the height of the prism is. Actually I'm pretty bad at math so don't even know how that equation should be solved :(

Comment: @Limpuls: Let $h$ be the height of the prism. Then, you can have $1620=2\times \text{(the area of the triangle)}+25h+29h+36h$. Then solve this for $h$.

Comment: I found in my book example on how it is being solved and the answer is 10 but I don't get where from does it come. It looks like this: **1620=90H + 2x360**

Comment: @Limpuls:  The equation you wrote is the same as the one I wrote where $H=h$ represents the height of the prism. The 1620 comes from the surface area. The 360 represents the area of the triangle. We have two triangles, so $2\times 360$. $90H$ comes from $25H+29H+36H$ where $25H$ represents the area of the rectangle $A_1B_1BA$ and so on. Note that we have three rectangles $A_1B_1BA, B_1C_1CB$ and $C_1A_1AC$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it helps, I really appreciate your time I almost got this one,  but the answer of **10** is found in the book. I get different answers of equation myself. I think I solve my equation wrong. Do you multiply **2** times **360** get **720** then add **90H** and divide by something?

Comment: @Limpuls: Since $2\times 360=720$. So, you have $1620=90H+720$. Now subtract $720$ from the both sides to get $1620-720=90H+720-720$. So, you have $900=90H$. Now divide the both sides by $90$ to get $H=10$.

Comment: Finally got this, thank you a lot, helped me a lot :)